# SQLite min() and max() on strings (memcmp comparison)

Tags: sqlite

I'm checking [Graphserver](http://graphserver.github.com/graphserver/)'s code and there is some SQLite command that intend to find the minimum and maximum value of two fields:

`select min(start_date), max(end_date) from calendar`

The start_date and end_date are in format like YYYYMMDD, which doesn't look to be one of the format recognized by SQLite in http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html. The min() and max() documented here http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html says that Binary collating function is used for comparison. Here ( http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#collation ) it says memcmp() is used for comparison. So it it just comparing byte by byte from the beginning of the string on the ascii numbers? I'm not sure what memcmp does. So 20120506 is suppose to be smaller than 20120507, and since 6 is 54 in ascii and 7 is 55 is ascii, 20120507 is bigger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that your dates are stored in a format that is not usable by SQLite date and time functions is not relevant to how the `min` and `max` function will operate on them.

The answer to your question is yes, if your dates are treated as strings by SQLite. If you store your dates as `YYYYMMDD`, then, depending on your column definition, your dates may actually be treated as numbers, and so compared as such.

For more on this, read about [data types](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html), and more specifically about [type affinity](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity).

Comment: The case I have is the column is TEXT. But of course they're all digits in there.